# I don't understand the expected specs for GeoJSON data in OpenLayers whether readFeatures() / readFeature() / readGeometry() are used?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I work on a GIS web app using GeoDjango and I struggle reading and displaying a multipoint geometry on my map.

If I serialize my GEOSGeometry object to GeoJSON, I can get the following JSON file :

```
{ "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ X0, Y0, Z0 ], [ X1, Y1, Z1 ], ... ]}
```

Now, when I want to read this data using `readGeometry()` as follows

```js
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readGeometry(geojson_object),
    });
```

I get the error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data`

I tried parsing my data using GeoJSONLint but it does seem correct.

So I tried to use `readFeature()` (as I only have one feature) as a matter of testing with slight modification to my geojson file :

```
{ "type": "Feature", "geometry" : { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ X0, Y0, Z0 ], [ X1, Y1, Z1 ], ... ] } }
```

Then I get `TypeError: n.features.getArray is not a function`

Again, if I use `readFeatures()` on the same feature object, I get no error whereas it should expect a collection of features, right ?

What am I missing ? The openlayers documentation is not that clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature property in a vector source must be an array of features.  Only readFeatures returns an array.  Results from the other methods need to be made into an array of features

```
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson_object),

    features: [ (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeature(geojson_object) ],

    features: [ new ol.Feature((new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readGeometry(geojson_object)) ],
```

Comment: Crystal clear, thank you. Also, just for the record and if anybody still have a `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name` kind of error, and using Django templating, be sure to escape your variable with `escapejs` like so `var data = "{{ variable.geom.json | escapejs }}"` otherwise, you get some `&quote` making your parser fail.